# clojure: Can't access non-public fields in the same package

Tags: clojure

In my clojure program I cannot access package scoped fields of the java class com.foo.Foo although I am in the namespace "com.foo" (via "(ns com.foo)" at the top of my clojure program). However, public fields in com.foo.Foo are accessible.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

First, the namespace com.foo is compiled to a class foo_whatever in package com; it's *not* compiled to a class in package com.foo.

See:

```
user> (ns com.foo)
nil
com.foo> 
nil
com.foo> (defn hello[] "hello !")
#'com.foo/hello
com.foo> (class hello)
com.foo$hello
com.foo> (ns com.foo.hello)
nil
com.foo.hello> (defn hi[] "hi !")
#'com.foo.hello/hi
com.foo.hello> (class hi)
com.foo.hello$hi
```

Second, when looking for constructors or fields, the Clojure compiler uses methods [getConstructor](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.2.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L2062) and [getFields](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.2.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Reflector.java#L298) from java.lang.Class, which, by spec, only return the [public constructors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29) and [public fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29).

So, bad luck here. It seems you won't be able to access package-protected fields.

**Edit**, answering comments. The best approach for accessing package-level fields in legacy Java code would be to write a class in Java that wraps the existing class and which exposes the package protected methods and fields from that class with public methods. This way, you have more control over the name and package of the generated class.

This wrapper is a small amount of Java code, and from there you can access the fields from Clojure code.

Comment: As I read the getField() documentation, it doesn't say it can only access public fields. getFields() - note the s - does. I don't see any hard restrictions on using getField directly from clojure code provided it's run from the right package. It would be ugly, but so is pretty much any use of package-scoped fields.

Comment: Clojure compiler uses getFields(), not getField as I answered previouly. Fixed the answer.

Comment: As you might have guessed, I want to use Clojure in an existing Java project, so not being able to easily access non-public existing Java code is a bit of a downer. I wonder why the implementation is using getFields() instead of getField(). So just to get that right: Even if I would understand enough about clojure namespaces to create clojure code that is interpreted by the JVM as belonging to a package com.foo, I would not be able to access package-scoped methods and fields in com.foo with pure clojure, i.e. without resorting to using methods like getField() inside my clojure code?